# How do I programmatically stop execution in a cell in Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I would like to programmatically stop execution in a Colab cell when certain error conditions are detected. Here is some sample code:

```
do_stuff()

if error_condition1:
    print("An error occurred")
    exit()

do_more_stuff()

if error_condition2:
    print("Another error occurred")
    exit()

do_even_more_stuff()
```

However, `exit()` seems to have no effect as cell always continues to execute even when the condition variables are `True` (unlike in normal Python environments). `sys.exit()` does "work" but throws a `SystemExit` exception.

I could rewrite the code to execute the key commands when errors are *not* found, but that becomes unwieldy if multiple conditions are checked:

```
do_stuff()

if not error_condition1:
    do_more_stuff()
    if not error_condition2:
        do_even_more_stuff()
    else:
        print("Another error occurred")
else:
    print("An error occurred")
```

So far, the best solution I've found is to put the code in a function and use `return` to exit the function:

```
def foo() -> None:
    if condition:
        do_stuff_here()
    else:
        return
```

Is there a more elegant solution?